# On canvas context rotate, any drawing made on canvas is getting drawn on the default canvas context?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
var image = new Image();
image.src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg"

image.onload = function() {
    var maxsize = image.width;
    var w = maxsize;
    var ratio = (image.width / w);//1
    var h = (image.height / ratio);
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;
    ctx.canvas.width = image.width;
    ctx.canvas.height = image.height;
    //c.width = image.width;
    //c.height = image.height;
    ctx.translate(w, h);
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI);
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,w,h);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 100);
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

On canvas rotate function below, any context ctx drawing, it is being drawn on the default image orientation the cooridnates (0,0) on bottom right. How to fill rect on the rotated image (0,0)instead?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I just commented out

```
//c.width = image.width;
//c.height = image.height;
```

because I don't know what is c.

By the way: you have useless code in that function.

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")


var image = new Image();
image.src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg"

image.onload = function() {
    var maxsize = image.width;
    var w = maxsize;
    var ratio = (image.width / w);//1
    var h = (image.height / ratio);
    canvas.width = w;
    canvas.height = h;
    ctx.canvas.width = image.width;
    ctx.canvas.height = image.height;
    //c.width = image.width;
    //c.height = image.height;
    
    ctx.save();
    
    ctx.translate(w, h);
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI);
    ctx.drawImage(image,0,0,w,h);
    
    ctx.restore();
    
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 100);
    }
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: i want to draw rect on image on the rotated canvas and it being drawn on the default orientation.

Comment: I've updated the code. In this case you need to save the context before transforming and restore the context before drawing the rect

Comment: and if i have multiple rotation.. then how to accomplish it?

Comment: Multiple rotation? please ask a different question explaining exactly what do you mean by _multiple rotation_  and what you intent to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

To reset the current transformation matrix of your context, you can use the [`setTransform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform) method, with an identity matrix (`1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0`)

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
var image = new Image();
image.src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg"

image.onload = function() {
  var maxsize = image.width;
  var w = maxsize;
  var ratio = (image.width / w); //1
  var h = (image.height / ratio);
  canvas.width = w;
  canvas.height = h;

  ctx.translate(w, h);
  ctx.rotate(Math.PI);
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, w, h);

  // reset the transform matrix
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);

  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 150, 100);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```